# Specifically, what does % do in C#?

Tags: c#

I have never came across anything that requires me to use it, and when I google what it does nothing comes up.

So, can someone please explain in detail, what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the modulus operator.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) Link, although it doesn't have a great example.

It basically gets the remainder, when the first number is divided by the second.

Like `7 % 3 = 1`. You can [play with this on google.](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&q=7%20%25%203&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=f&oq=)

As [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) says, *modding* different types (doubles,decimals) results those types.

The most common use is in programs that need to check for an even number:

```
 n % 2 == 0;// if the mod of n by 2 (remainder) is zero then n is even
```

---

Specifically like @[BenVoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) says `modulus`  actually takes the sign of the dividend.(unlike remainder which takes the sign of the divisor) It seems some languages **implement** it this way, there is a [list here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). So C# takes the sign of the dividend.

```
-7 % 3 = -1//in C#
-6 % 2 = 0// so even checks work ok with negative numbers in C#
```

But the [result from google is 2](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&q=-7%20%25%203&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=)?

Answer (score 4):

It is the [Modulo Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Returns the remainder when one integer is divided by another.

Comment: "modulo" and "remainder" operations aren't quite the same, one takes the sign of the divisor and the other takes the sign of the dividend.

Comment: ah true, tho, [wiki on modules.common pitfalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls) says  **some** languages implement it this way._(when the mod takes the sign takes the dividend)_

Comment: ah and there is also a list of how each language implements this! =)

Answer (score 0):

It is the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_%28algebraic_number_theory%29) operator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Answer (score -1):

It lets you know what is left over once the first number has been divided by the second as many times as it can.  For example:

- 5 % 2 = 1

  - Because 2 can only go into 5, 2 times (4), then all you have is 1 left over.
- 5 % 2.2 = 0.6

  - Because 2.2*2 is 4.4 and 5-4.4 is 0.6.